# Tool to manage Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, jdbc

I need a solution that will simplify my working pattern. The idea is that I need a tool whit which to connect to a SQLite database owned by an app (app from a connected real device or emulator). 
The direction in which I started is taken from here (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite) : add sqlite jdbc driver improvization and with Eclipse (with DTP plugin) manage db (delete columns, do inserts etc..).. so this is all in vain, because I have no idea how to express the path to a db located in my device

Anyways. Suggestions, tools?

Comment: If the DB is stored in internal (private) memory and the device isn't rooted then it can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

From a remote shell to your device you can use the [sqlite3](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/sqlite3.html) command-line program to manage SQLite databases created by Android applications.